# Installing `at` on Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, updates

I am running a bunch of simulations on several machines. Each of these machines posts a "request" to a server, which then `ssh`es back into this machine to schedule a run of the appropriate simulation.
For example:

`machine1` posts a request
server `ssh`es into `machine1` and schedules a run of `simulation1`

`machine3` posts a request
server `ssh`es into `machine3` and schedules a run of `simulation2`

`machine2` posts a request
server `ssh`es into `machine2` and schedules a run of `simulation3`

… and so on.

The scheduling of the running of a simulation is done by using the `at` command on linux.
Since some of the computers that I'm using to run these simulations use windows (university computer, so I can't wipe and install linux), I installed Cygwin. The problem is that I had to install a minimal version of Cygwin, which I didn't know at the time, didn't include the `at` command. Now, I want to install the `at` command.

I'm open to reinstalling Cygwin if I really have to, though I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require me to do so.

How can I get the `at` command working on Cygwin?

I tried using `apt-cyg` (`apt-cyg install at`), but that didn't work. I think the problem is that I don't know what package the `at` command is located in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unix `at` command does not appear installable on Cygwin. However, there does exist and `at` command with a slightly different syntax (same functionality) built into windows, which is what Cygwin uses. This is already installed with a default Cygwin install

Answer (score 0):

Actualy when you run the setup again it will detect the current version and you can just add packages.

Comment: Which package contains the `at` command?